# Precompute Jupyter widget results and embed in HTML

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working on a Jupyter notebook that creates an energy level diagram using matplotlib. One parameter of the underlaying spectrum computation can be varied using an interact statement. Now I want to export this notebook to HTML while the widget functionality should stay intact. Is it possible to precompute all possible outcomes and include them into the HTML version? Users should be able to use the interact feature without having to connect to a kernel.

Thanks for advice.

Peter

**EDIT**: I hope to clarify my question with the following sample code:

```python
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    x = np.linspace(0,2,100)
    plt.plot(x,a*x**2)
    plt.ylim([0,20])
    plt.show()
    return None

interact(f, a=(1,5,1))
```

In the final HTML file all possible images (in this case all parabolas with a=1...5) should be included (in this sense pre-computed) and then displayed when the user selects the appropiate value with the slider.

Comment: How exactly should the `interact` process anything without being able to call python command through a kernel?

Comment: Well, I want to precompute all possible outcomes before exporting the static HTML. So, all possible results are stored in the HTML and showed when the user moves the slider of the interact-widget. I know that depending on the possibilites this can enlarge the file size enormously. I added a sample code to my question to clarify this.

Comment: `interact` is a python command, so it needs python to work. Possibly there are other methods to create a dropdown in a jupyter notebook, which would use javascript and could hence be incorporated into the html file - I'm not an expert of that - all I'm saying is that using `interact` this is not possible.